# client disconnects when calling HBase endpoint

Tags: java, hbase

I'm using hbase 0.94.15 (no cluster setup).

I adapted the `BulkDeleteEndpoing` (see org.apache.hadoop.hbase.coprocessor.example.BulkDeleteEndpoint) and am calling it from the client.

It works fine for a *limited* amount of data (probably around 20.000 rows wrt our table design), but after that I get an error containing `responseTooSlow` and `execCoprocessor`.

I've read that this is due to a client disconnect, as it doesn't get any response within 60 seconds (default `hbase.rpc.timeout`) (https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/nosql-databases/FPeMLHrYkco).

My question now is, how do I prevent the client from closing the connection before the endpoint is done?

- I do not want to set the default rpc timeout to some high value (setting the timeout for this specific call only would be an option, but would only be a workaround)
- in some mailing list I found a comment that it is able to *poll* for the status of the endpoint, but (1) I can't find the site anymore, and (2) I can't find any other information regarding this idea. Maybe it is available in some more recent version?

any other ideas are appreciated

Answer (score 0):

What we might try is limit the scope of the scan object (may be calling
Scan.setMaxResultsPerColumnFamily()) and invoking the co-processor in a loop,
with the startKey updated in every iteration. Need to figure out how to update
the startKey at the end of every invocation.